# Difference between codespace and codepoint

Tags: binary, utf

Hello fellow programmers,

Would anyone know what the difference between a codespace and a codepoint is in relation to character encoding? My idea on this is that a codepoint is the representation of a certain character through a binary digit, and that codespace is the range of a certain set of codepoints.

Comment: Can you quote/link the article where this terminology is used? I don't think "codespace" is a common term with regards to Unicode.

Comment: @Thilo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point

Comment: Well, there you go :-)  The code space is made up by the sum of all code points.

Comment: haha, thanks @Thilo